# iPad launch image works in sim but not on device

Tags: ipad, ios, plist

Like the title says..

I've added an entry to the info.plist to specify a png file as the launch image. It's just a screengrab of the table view, 'shopped to remove content. 
In the simulator it appears and looks fine.

However when I deploy and run on a device it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

iOS 4.2.1, Xcode 3.2.5

Comment: Do you have the file extension in the Info.plist entry? It should only have the basename, but the simulator might ignore this.

Comment: yep, I do. Good thought, I'll try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean build on your device, you may have an old Default.png canceling out your new one.